# Facebook Comment Box Disappears in Accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, facebook, facebook-comments

I have two examples of Facebook comment box failing to load when an accordian is collapsed and reloaded. One HTML/JavaScript basic and the other in a Wordpress site via Visual Composer - this problem also occurs in numerous other accordions

HTML Example - http://iknowdigital.co.uk/htmlexample/

Wordpress Via Visual Composer http://thesingingmajor.co.uk/test-comment-box-martin/

I have contacted Facebook Support and Visual Composer support and neither can help out.

here are the replies

From VC

> Hi Martin, The issue is not with the iframe, but the js that facebook comments use to render. It is not able to re-initialize itself when it is displayed as hidden and hence the issue occur. You can see that when you add nay iframe, it works fine without any issue. It is the js from the comments which is restricting it. As mentioned previously, it will require some custom js code to re-initialize this loading when the closed (hidden) accordion is opened. Kindly check.

From Facebook

> Hi Martin,The issue here is the way the library is working. If you debug the code you'll see the plugin does not disappear, the issue is that the library is changing the width of the iframe that contains the plugin to 0 and you cannot see the comments plugin. In order to avoid this situation you will have to manually change the width value again and you'll see the comment plugin is still there. I'm going to close this bug as "By design" as this is not an issue in our side.

I'm not a javascript programmer, so am really at a loss here. Can anyone chip in with some advice here?

Thanks Martin

Comment: When I look at your first example page, the iframe dimensions seem fine – looks like it might rather be the accordion script you’re using that doesn’t handle the content height correctly. I’d suggest you go look for proper accordion implementation …

Comment: There is a bug open and assigned here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/649430125198006/